# Delete file after upload

Tags: java, nio

I want to implement file upload from web page into database. I need to create some tempolary file which will be used to transfer the file from the web page to the database. I found this Java example;

```
    public void copyFileLocation() throws IOException {

        File temp = File.createTempFile("temp-file-name", ".tmp");

    }
```

Is there a way to delete the file automatically after successfull copy? Also is this code platform independent? I need to create the tanpolary files on diffrent platforms in tmp folder.

Comment: In principle there is no need to upload to a (temporary) File. One could immediately write the upload to the database.

Comment: "after successfull copy?" what copy?? Did you consider using `File#renameTo`?

Comment: Once it gets copied use `File#delete()`

Comment: And beside using delete, you might want to put some try/finally around that; to make sure you don't miss to delete temporary files upon exceptions are thrown at you.

Comment: @JoopEggen can you give some example? It will be very usefull to see working example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the uploaded data immediately in the database, assuming a column with SQL type BLOB.

```
try (PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(
        "INSERT INTO files(blob) VALUES(?)");

    // Either:
    InputStream in = ... uploaded file
    // or:
    byte[] data = ... uploaded file contents
    ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);

    stmt.setBinaryStream(1, in);
    stmt.executeUpdate();
}
```

(There are several upload solutions.)

The advantage is less shoveling done.

Comment: Well, I was thinking for a such a solution but I'm not sure if I skip the step with the file on filesystem and a middle memory buffer(let's say it this way) correct if I'm wrong but'RAM memory will be used to store tempolary the data. And If I have 2 GB file on VPS with 1 GB RAM the result will be not very good. Can you extend your example please? It's not very clear what should I use InputStream  or byte[].

Comment: `byte[]` indeed is memory hungry. In general InputStream should be possible. And as JDBC _reads streamed_ there is no large memory consumption. And how else would one in the end store the file when not by JDBC in the same manner. **Storing paths to permanent files** would be another solution. Makes backups easier. Could use UUIDs as names.